# Passing * as a command line argument

Tags: c, command-line-arguments, postfix-notation

I wrote a C program to evaluate reverse polish notation by passing the expression as a command line argument, but when I pass * (for multiplication) then it is passing all the file names in that folder.

For example I passed this :

./rpn 10 20 30 + *

and when I print all the arguments result is,

```
 10
 20
 30
 +
 gcd
 gcd.c
 gcd.c~
 rpn
 rpn.c
 rpn.c~
 swapmacro
 swapmacro.c argc :12
```

Comment: What program are you using to pass a `*` to your program? It sounds like you just don't know how to use whatever program you are using to launch your C program.

Comment: I am using ubuntu 12.04 terminal to run my program, is that what you are asking?

Comment: Its called **filename Expansion**: lets try this code `for i in *;do echo $i;done;` at your shell

Comment: No. The terminal must be displaying the output of some program and you must be sending your input to some program. I'm asking what that program is. I'm betting if you have no idea what program that is, you also have no idea how to use it. That's *well* worth learning. The program you are using is commonly referred to as a "shell". And you should intelligently choose the shell you use rather than blindly accepting your platform's default and you should learn *everything* you can about it.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Ok I will start reading it. And I am using bash.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan It gives all the names of file in that folder, as it was giving in place of *. I don't know shell script so I just copy paste that script of yours.Thanks for the kind reply.

Comment: @ParagJain Yes this I wanted to demonstrate using this small code, you may like to read [**3.5 Shell Expansions**](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Expansions) Its called Filename Expantion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the `*` e.g. by quoting it like `"*"` or by escaping it like `\*`

The expansion of `*` is done by the shell (before starting your program). Read e.g. the [Advanced Bash Scripting guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/).

Comment: Also, using ~ as an argument will expand to the current directory.

Comment: @aaronvan: No, wrong. The `~`  expands to the *home* directory (which `$HOME` often is)

Answer (score 4):

This is not a C problem.  You're using Bash (or some equivalent shell), where `*` is automatically expanded (before it gets anywhere near your program).  You'll need to do something like this:

```
./rpn 10 20 30 + "*"
```

Comment: That works ,thanks. But is there something which I can do to stop it, I am running ubuntu terminal how would I know that It will expand or not in particular environment?