Issues with using * in command line in windows
I was trying to solve the reverse polish calculator problem where the arguments can be entered on the command line. I am facing a peculiar problem. The program name is rpc.exe
A command line entry as follows:
E:\>rpc 1 2 3 + 

returns an argc value of 5, as expected.
However, if one of the arguments is *, the argc value goes totally haywire.
Consider this:
E:\>rpc 1 2 3 *

returns an argc value of 32.
I believe this is messing up my program because the program works fine for all operations except multiplication.
This problem does not arise if I use x or X in the program instead of *.
What could be the reason for this, and how do I fix it?
P.S. I am using Code::Blocks 20.03 with GCC on Windows 8.1

Try rpc 1 2 3 "*" or rpc 1 2 3 \*, otherwise * is expanded to all files in current directory.

Tangential: why is the 1 ignored?  Should the calculator not complain about the unused argument?

@JonathanLeffler What makes you think that 1 is ignored?

@thebusybee: The fact that 2 + 3 = 5 and the 1 has not self-evidently contributed to that calculation.  It could be that the design is Usage: rpc "number of operators" operand ... operator ..., but that's quite obscure.  Or there could be some other explanation.

The question ia similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17691785/passing-as-a-command-line-argument but not exactly the same because I am not getting the output as mentioned in that question.  Thank you.

Do you get the correct result if you use "*" or '*' or \* instead?

@JonathanLeffler The only "5" I find is in "returns an argc value of 5" (emphasis by me). Do you mean that?

@VinayakDeshmukh Please extend your program to print all arguments, and you will see. Of course you will not see the same output, because the programs are different, and the content of your working directory.

@the busybee, thanks. I tried expanding the program to print all the arguments and it does print a list of all the files in the concerned folder / directory. :(

I replaced the * in my program with 'x' and the program works fine.

To clean up this site, you might want to consider to delete your question.

Ok, will do that. Thank you. But the question does remain unanswered.

The question is answered. Your program is receiving the list of all files that match *. If you want to pass * as an argument, you have to escape it as suggested by different people in the comments.
